# OnEdit event handling and blank cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to test if a cell in column An is empty upon clicking on a cell in column C. If it is empty, then to populate that cell in Column A with variable newValue.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var newValue=10
  var range = e.range;
  var offsetRange = offset(0,-2).range;
  if (isblank().offsetRange) {offsetRange.setValue(newValue);}
}
```

The basic goal is to incorporate functionality from this test code above into the creation of a primary key, where primary key values are stored in Column A. I'm working on a simple table view database in Spreadsheet. If the user initiates data entry into a blank cell in Column C (i.e. presumably creating a new record/row), and the corresponding row's Column A is blank (lacks a primary key), then the code will generate and populate A with a unique number within column A as a primary key (I can workout generating unique numbers later).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your script makes sense, but you made a few mistakes:

1. Spreadsheet functions, such as `isblank`, are not available in Apps Script.
2. Method names appear *after* the object to which the method is applied. That is: `range.offset(0, -2)`, not `offset(0, -2).range`
3. A **range** is not the same as a **value** in that range. To get the value(s), use `getValue` or `getValues` as appropriate.
4. Blank cells appear to contain empty strings from Apps Script's perspective. So the test for blank is `offsetRange.getValue() === ''`, as below.

Correct script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var newValue = 10;
  var range = e.range;
  var offsetRange = range.offset(0, -2);
  if (offsetRange.getValue() === '') {
    offsetRange.setValue(newValue);
  }
}
```